# Open URL in a different Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement in which when a user clicks on an URL in Chrome, the link should open in IE.

Any ideas how to achieve this using jquery or javascript??

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can do this in Javascript. It can't run other applications.

Comment: What if the user doesn't have IE?

Comment: any other work arounds?

Comment: Its a given that user has IE

Comment: What kind of requirement is that? Why do you want this?

Comment: You can write a chrome extension and a chrome native messaging host.

Comment: The only workaround is to have another protocol like, "openApp:iexplorer.exe http://yourwebsite.com", similar to how skype has "skype:phone-number". That would work for users that have your application installed.

Comment: If your link only works in IE (I assume that's why it has to be opened in IE), and it's a given that your users will definitely have IE (so, presumably, some sort of company-specific application), why not just tell them they have to use IE?

Comment: The link opens a third party application that works only in IE with active X. Our company-specific Application is Siebel Open UI intended to use in Chrome. so its complicated like that

Comment: @DaveChen Can you please tell me how to use  protocol like, "openApp:iexplorer.exe yourwebsite.com"?

Comment: @bharath Have you tried the ietab2 extension? Seems like a better option. The protocol works in the same way skype would work. An extension. So just go with the ietab2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with vanilla JavaScript.

**Update:** Yes, there's a workaround, which will work only for browsers with [IETab](http://www.ietab.net/) extension installed. That way, you can force your links to something like this:

> chrome://ietab2/content/reloaded.html?url=http://example.com

That way the `http://example.com` will be run using IE engine.

Comment: any other work arounds?

Comment: Yes, see my updated answer. Actually, I saw that's mentioned in question marked as duplicate. There you can found more workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use jquery or js to change the behavior of windows's default applications, for instance if their default browser is chrome then your url will open in chrome